# A inital value problem $x' = f(x), x(0) = 1$ that has more than one solution?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

A inital value problem $x' = f(x), x(0) = 1$ that has more than one solution?

is this possible? if so, could you show me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, try:

$$x'= x^{1/2}, x(0) = 1$$

Using separation of variables, we find:

$$x(t) = \dfrac{1}{4}(t+c_1)^2$$

Solving for the IC, we have two solutions:

$$x(t) = \dfrac{1}{4}(t + 2)^2, ~~x(t) = \dfrac{1}{4}(t -2)^2$$

One can come up with more examples too:

- $x' = x^{3/2}$
- $x' = |x|$
- $\ldots$

Comment: how about f(x) = |x|?

Comment: Sure, that works too, as does $x' = x^{3/2}$.